# como puedo seleccionar lo que tengo en mi base de datos en este archivo de php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

buenas! mi problema es que quiero poner un select de 2 tablas pero no me deja mi archivo de PHP. este es el codigo

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$paginaActual = $_POST['partida'];

$nroProductos = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipo_emergencia"));
$nroLotes = 10;
$nroPaginas = ceil($nroProductos/$nroLotes);
$lista = '';
$tabla = '';

if($paginaActual > 1){
    $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.($paginaActual-1).');">Anterior</a></li>';
}
for($i=1; $i<=$nroPaginas; $i++){
    if($i == $paginaActual){
        $lista = $lista.'<li class=""><a href="javascript:pagination('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }else{
        $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
}
if($paginaActual < $nroPaginas){
    $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.($paginaActual+1).');">Siguiente</a></li>';
}

if($paginaActual <= 1){
    $limit = 0;
}else{
    $limit = $nroLotes*($paginaActual-1);
}

$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipo_emergencia LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes");


$tabla = $tabla.'<table class="table table-bordered table-inverse">
                    <tr class="bg-primary">

                        <th width="300">Emergencia</th>

                        <th width="50">Opciones</th>
                    </tr>';

while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
    $tabla = $tabla.'<tr>
                        <td>'.$registro2['nombre'].'</td>

                        <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id_tipo'].');"  class="glyphicon-pencil"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id_tipo'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
                      </tr>';       
}


$tabla = $tabla.'</table>';
$array = array(0 => $tabla,
               1 => $lista);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

quiero que en el select ponga esto de mi base de datos

```
Select Tipo_emergencia.Id_Tipo, Tipo_emergencia.Nombre,  clasificacion_emergencia.nombre_clas  FROM tipo_emergencia,clasificacion_emergencia WHERE tipo_emergencia.id_clasificacion=clasificacion_emergencia.id_clasificacion; LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes
```

pero al momento de ejecutarlo en el navegador no me sale nada. la base de datos ya esta bien [image: esta es la imagen]

en pocas palabras quiero que me muestre eso en la interfaz de la base de datos. ya lo puse en el select pero no me deja. gracias

Comment: Coloca el código como lo tienes en tu script; no veo en ninguna parte el "select ..." que dices no te sale en el navegador. Solo veo "SELECT * FROM tipo_emergencia LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes" y sin "LIMIT" pero con el "FROM tipo_emergencia,clasificacion_emergencia " que por cierto salvo sea un error al escribir/copiar "FROM -> tipo_emergencia,clasificacion_emergencia " ese "->" no debe ir.

Comment: Quiero advertir que independientemente si te dan alguna solución a tu problema, consideres **usar otro tipo de conexión a tu base de datos**. Todas las funciones `mysql_*` están desactualizadas debido a que acceden a nuestra base de datos de forma **insegura** y podrías sufrir ataques de **Inyección SQL**. _Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL._  http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas eso es todo mi script, con todo eso me da una ventana donde solo me da el nombre pero quiero el nombre y la clasificacion.

Comment: Pones el nombre: `<td>'.$registro2['nombre'].'</td>`pero en ningún momento pones la clasificación. Los datos que quieras, si tu consulta a la bd funciona bien, debes extraerlos como haces con el nombre. Y verifica que tu tabla esté bien cuadrada, que no tenga en una parte `<td>...</td>` de más o de menos, de lo contrario no verías algunos `<td>...</td>` .

Comment: no lo pongo por que aunque se lo ponga no me va a dejar, por que en el select no me deja

Comment: _En el select no me deja_ No entiendo lo que quieres decir. ¿En qué tabla se encuentra el dato `clasificacion` que quieres mostrar? Si haces `SELECT clasificacion, otrascolumnas.... FROM ...` tendrás en el resultado las columnas que hayas puesto en el SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Este sería el código adaptado:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
/* $_POST['partida'], debería ser validado y escapado */
$paginaActual = $_POST['partida'];
/* obtienes el número de registros de la nueva consulta */
$nroProductos = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
SELECT 
    Tipo_emergencia.Id_Tipo, 
    Tipo_emergencia.Nombre,
    clasificacion_emergencia.nombre_clas 
FROM 
    tipo_emergencia,
    clasificacion_emergencia 
WHERE
    tipo_emergencia.id_clasificacion=clasificacion_emergencia.id_clasificacion
"));

$nroLotes = 10;
$nroPaginas = ceil($nroProductos/$nroLotes);
$lista = '';
$tabla = '';

if($paginaActual > 1){
    $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.($paginaActual-1).');">Anterior</a></li>';
}
for($i=1; $i<=$nroPaginas; $i++){
    if($i == $paginaActual){
        $lista = $lista.'<li class=""><a href="javascript:pagination('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }else{
        $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
}
if($paginaActual < $nroPaginas){
    $lista = $lista.'<li><a href="javascript:pagination('.($paginaActual+1).');">Siguiente</a></li>';
}

if($paginaActual <= 1){
    $limit = 0;
}else{
    $limit = $nroLotes*($paginaActual-1);
}
/* Aquí modificamos por la consulta deseada */
$registro = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    Tipo_emergencia.Id_Tipo, 
    Tipo_emergencia.Nombre,
    clasificacion_emergencia.nombre_clas 
FROM 
    tipo_emergencia,
    clasificacion_emergencia 
WHERE
    tipo_emergencia.id_clasificacion=clasificacion_emergencia.id_clasificacion 
LIMIT 
    $limit, $nroLotes
");

/* Añades las columnas nuevas a la tabla */
$tabla .= '
    <table class="table table-bordered table-inverse">
    <tr class="bg-primary">
        <th width="300">Id_Tipo</th>
        <th width="300">Emergencia</th>
        <th width="300">Nombre</th>
        <th width="50">Opciones</th>
    </tr>';

while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
    /* Aquí añades los datos que se mostrarán para cada fila */
    $tabla .='
    <tr>
        <td>'.$registro2['Id_Tipo'].'</td>
        <td>'.$registro2['Nombre'].'</td>
        <td>'.$registro2['nombre_clas'].'</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id_tipo'].');"  class="glyphicon-pencil"></a>
            <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id_tipo'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>';       
}


$tabla .= '</table>';
$array = array(0 => $tabla,
               1 => $lista);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Obviamente hay cosas que se deberían cambiar por ejemplo:

- mysql_* esta obsoleto, en su lugar debería de utilizarse mysqli_*, [info](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)
- En la primera consulta mysql_num_rows() debería ser evitado, ya que traes todos los registros para luego contarlos y nada más, no se utilizan. En su lugar deberías crear una consulta que retorne el número total de registros directamente.
- Puedes concatenar directamente con **.=** en lugar de hacer `$lista = $lista.'más texto';`
- **include** es un constructor del lenguaje y los paréntesis son prescindibles.
- Deberías de validar y escapar los datos adecuadamente, para prevenir inyección sql independientemente de que utilices mysql_* o mysqli_*, en este caso concreto solo recibes una variable `$_POST['partida'];` deberías asegurarte se que siempre es un número para evitar la inyección y en caso de no serlo evitar la ejecución de la consulta.

Comment: Hola Xerif, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te comento que el formato de código se hace identando con 4 espacios (si seleccionas el código y le das click al ícono `{}` lo hará por ti) y sería bueno que en tus respuestas expliques un poco qué cosas has cambiado, por qué y cómo resuelven el problema. Te invito a [hacer el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y a consultar nuestra guía [*Cómo responder*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar al OP que le estás dando una solución basada en funciones declaradas obsoletas en PHP porque son peligrosas? Me refiero a las funciones mysql_... Además, si se usa PHP 7 ese código no funcionará. Bueno, es mejor que el código no funcione que sufrir una inyección SQL.